# Jar in a jar build with maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to create a .jar for my app. This app contains many things such as another .jar.

Using this plugin in my pom configuration :

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.rilent.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And I have this link to a local jar

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.sauronsoftware.jave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jave</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jave-1.0.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I am using this command to build my app which returns BUILD SUCCESS :

```
 mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

but when I try to execute my program, It crashes at some point returning this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/sauronsoftware/jave/InputFormatException
( a class from the .jar)
```

I tried decompressing my main jar to see its content : 
[image]

what is wrong with the way I am creating my jar?

edit @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen

I tried this way too, I added this to my pom :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jolira/onejar-maven-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

then I m compiling with `mvn compile` and when I try to run the .jar I get this error

`no main manifest attribute, in .\myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
what am I doing wrong again ...?

Note : My jar also contains a .exe

Answer (score 0):

The standard classloaders cannot load classes from jars inside jars.  EXE files cannot be run from inside jars.

This does not mean that it is impossible, but a bit cumbersome and perhaps above your current skill level.  You might find One Jar (http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) interesting as it automates exactly this.

For a Maven project I have had good experience with creating a deployment structure and scripts with appassembler.  http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/

Comment: You MUST read and understand the documentation for One Jar in order to use it!

Comment: heh I will try but the documentation seems rather limited when It comes to Maven...

Comment: Also, perhaps a stupid question but what the "standard classloaders" is supposed to do if It can't load the class from inside the jars? I don't see any benefit from using it then

Comment: I have updated my answer.   You will basically need more elbow grease.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it, I am already dealing with the .exe, I am saving it in a tmp file when the app starts and delete it afterwards but I thought it was important enough to be noticed as the onejar documentation only talks about embedded jars.